# Create new column with values from certain rows of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
(Example edited)

```
df <- data.frame(Subject = c(rep("A", 9), rep("B", 8)),
Trial = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
Feature_1 = c(rep(123, 2), 234, 345, rep(456, 2), 567, rep(678, 2), 831, rep(444, 2), 461, 921, rep(436, 2), 111),
Feature_2 = c(rep(321, 2), 543, 654, rep(765, 2), 876, rep(987, 2), 912, rep(302, 2), 900, 555, rep(382, 2), 197),
Feature_3 = c(rep(190, 2), 459, 392, rep(398, 2), 492, rep(587, 2), 761, rep(901, 2), 783, 312, rep(880, 2), 229),
Feature_correct = NA)

df
   Subject Trial Feature_1 Feature_2 Feature_3 Feature_correct
1        A     1       123       321       190              NA
2        A     1       123       321       190              NA
3        A     2       234       543       459              NA
4        A     3       345       654       392              NA
5        A     4       456       765       398              NA
6        A     4       456       765       398              NA
7        A     5       567       876       492              NA
8        A     6       678       987       587              NA
9        A     6       678       987       587              NA
10       B     1       831       912       761              NA
11       B     2       444       302       901              NA
12       B     2       444       302       901              NA
13       B     3       461       900       783              NA
14       B     4       921       555       312              NA
15       B     5       436       382       880              NA
16       B     5       436       382       880              NA
17       B     6       111       197       229              NA
```

What I need is for the `Feature_correct` column to contain the values from `Feature_n` depending on `Trial` for each `Subject`. So:

Subject A & Trials 1 and 2: Feature_correct contains the values for Subject A & Trials 1 and 2 under Feature_1 (respectively).

Subject A & Trials 3 and 4: Feature_correct contains the values for Subject A & Trials 3 and 4 under Feature_2 (respectively).

Subject A & Trials 5 and 6: Feature_correct contains the values for Subject A & Trials 5 and 6 under Feature_3 (respectively).

and so on for Subject B.

This is my goal:

```
df$Feature_goal <- c(rep(123, 2), 234, 654, rep(765, 2), 492, rep(587, 2), 831, rep(444, 2), 900, 555, rep(880, 2), 229)

head(df)
  Subject Trial Feature_1 Feature_2 Feature_3 Feature_correct Feature_goal
1       A     1       123       321       190              NA          123
2       A     1       123       321       190              NA          123
3       A     2       234       543       459              NA          234
4       A     3       345       654       392              NA          654
5       A     4       456       765       398              NA          765
6       A     4       456       765       398              NA          765
```

I know how to do this manually (specifying the Subject name and Trial number in the syntax), but I'd like to create a loop (or whatever else works) so that I don't have to type the name of each Subject (in my real dataset I have many participants and many "Feature" variables).

I've tried this `for` loop, but I get an error:

```
df <- for(i in 1:nrow(df$Subject)) {
 if(df$Trial %in% c(1,2)){
   df[df$Subject == i $ df$Trial %in% c(1,2),]$Feature_correct = df[df$Subject == i & df$Trial %in% c(1,2),]$Feature_1
 }
  if(df$Trial %in% c(3,4)){
   df[df$Subject == i $ df$Trial %in% c(3,4),]$Feature_correct = df[df$Subject == i & df$Trial %in% c(3,4),]$Feature_2
  }
  if(df$Trial %in% c(5,6)){
   df[df$Subject == i $ df$Trial %in% c(5,6),]$Feature_correct = df[df$Subject == i & df$Trial %in% c(5,6),]$Feature_3
 }
}

> Error in 1:nrow(df$Subject) : argument of length 0
```

Indeed,

```
nrow(df$Subject)
> NULL
```

Would anyone know how to make this work (with the loop or in any other way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized way would be to create a row/column index by pasting "Feature" with `Trial` number to `match` it with column names and subset values from original dataframe.

```
df$Feature_Goal <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
                      match(paste0("Feature_", df$Trial), names(df)))]
df

#   Subject Trial Feature_1 Feature_2 Feature_3 Feature_correct Feature_Goal
#1        A     1       123       321       190              NA          123
#2        A     1       123       321       190              NA          123
#3        A     2       234       543       459              NA          543
#4        A     2       234       543       459              NA          543
#5        A     3       345       654       392              NA          392
#6        A     3       345       654       392              NA          392
#7        B     1       456       765       398              NA          456
#8        B     1       456       765       398              NA          456
#9        B     2       567       876       492              NA          876
#10       B     2       567       876       492              NA          876
#11       B     3       678       987       587              NA          587
#12       B     3       678       987       587              NA          587
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! For my real dataset, though, this ends up not working because I have 24 trials corresponding to each of 4 "feature_" columns. My example was unfortunate, with number of trials and of "feature_"s matching. Should I edit my example in the question? (new to stack overflow, not sure if I should do that)

Comment: @offrede yes, please edit your example to show your exact input data and expected output for that.

Comment: Actually your solution still works perfectly with my original example. i only had to create a new column Trials2 in which Trials %in% c(1:2) are named as "1". Then, I use paste0("Feature_", df$Trial2). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a loop.

```
    for (i in 1:3) {
    idx <- which(df$Trial == i)
    df[idx,6] <- df[idx,i+2]
    }
```